# Split string by word in Oracle looking for abbreviations in a lookup table

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I've got a list of approx 100k pairs of text strings (sentences) which could mean the same, even if the values are different. A lot of the issues are simply due to using abbreviations and different punctuation on one half of the pair:

```
Source 1                Source 2
TEMP.IND.               TEMPERATURE INDICATOR
```

My initial thought on how to solve this would be to split the strings by word, and then look each word up in a table containing abbreviations and the full-length words similar to below:

```
Abbreviation:          Meaning:
TEMP.                  TEMPERATURE
IND.                   INDICATOR
```

If a match is found I generate a replacement string using the new word before comparing it with the other source. If they don't match, I repeat the process for each abbreviated word found in the lookup table.

Would this be very complex to do in Oracle, compared to eg. C# (which I'm fluent in)? Keeping it in the DB would be preferred, but not if it takes too much time to implement. Are there any better options? The alternative is to check everything manually.

Apologies if this is the wrong site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just as easy to do in the DB (Oracle) as to do in C#, and probably much, much faster. Writing the code isn't that much of a problem, once you create your equivalence tables (with the Abbreviation and Meaning columns).

The difficulty is in the specification. Why should Temp. Ind. mean "temperature indicator" and not "temporary index" or "temple in India"? This will work (in Oracle or C# or whatever, that is irrelevant) only if each abbreviation corresponds to a unique meaning.

Best of luck!

Comment: The texts I'm comparing comes from a very specific business domain, so there is no chance of a mixup. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Even so, you will need a strong set of rules before you start thinking about code. For example, should Temp. be expanded to Temperature and temp. to temperature (matching case)? Do you need to "sense" when Temp. is the last word in a sentence, so the period (full stop, . ending the sentence) is not deleted leaving the sentence without a period? Do you want temp.; and temp; to both be expanded to temperature; (all followed by semicolon ;)? Having these come up after you've already developed the code can be very frustrating.